# script for c# win form to display sql data in Reportviewer and Chart

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table in SQL2012 With fieldname id, Time, Counter. It is auto generated by an application which keep on logging counter value to counter and that value increment every moment. the time filed is datetime. I want to display this table in c# winforms in two formats, first in chart that could dislay counter value of real time recent value, last day with steps of 1 hour, last month and past years, it is similar to stocks charts. the trick here is counter value increases every moment.
Aslo need to display same data in reportviewer.

Please advise me a solution in visual studio 2012.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, questions that do not include any working code or do not show your effort in solving the problem are off topic. Please include your code, and ask a more _specific_ question.

Comment: I'm sorry, are you trying to show a value in MSChart in real time and update this value when changes? Where are you going to display this chart? In a windows form? Please take a look at the examples located in this site: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61]

Answer (score 0):

The link i provided contains tons of examples you can use to work with this. I've only worked with MSCharts before to create only static images of these charts to print them in reports, but i can help.

I suppose you already have added the MSChart component to your form and specified the type of table (pie chart, line chart, etc.) you want to use.

The first thing you will need to do is to databind the data you need to the table. This code is taken from the samples link i gave to you:

```
  // Access database
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Utilities.SampleMain.MainForm mainForm = (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Utilities.SampleMain.MainForm)this.ParentForm;
string fileNameString = mainForm.applicationPath + "\\data\\chartdata.mdb";

// Initialize a connection string    
string myConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileNameString;

// Define the database query    
string mySelectQuery="SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE;";

// Create a database connection object using the connection string    
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString);

// Create a database command on the connection using query    
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);

// Open the connection    
myCommand.Connection.Open();

// Create a database reader    
OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

// Since the reader implements and IEnumerable, pass the reader directly into
// the DataBindTable method with the name of the Column to be used as the XValue
Chart1.DataBindTable(myReader, "Date");

// Close the reader and the connection
myReader.Close();
myConnection.Close();
```

Once you managed to display your data in the MSChart the way you needed, you need to create a "Update" method which will be executed a certain amount of time to update the values on your table.